# Get 1 or 0 value of multiple checkboxs depending if they are checked

Tags: php, checkbox, foreach

I want to get either a 1 or 0 value from multiple checkboxes depending on if they are checked or not.

I have rows of fields

```
activity    duration [checkbox] date
activity    duration [checkbox] date
activity    duration [checkbox] date
activity    duration [checkbox] date

<select name="activities[]">
    <option value="12">Football</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="duration[]" placeholder="" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="is_distance[]" value="1">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="datepicker[]" id="">
```

When the fields have content they will look something like this

```
Football   90  1 2019-05-09
Cycling    120 0 2019-05-09
Cricket    70  0 2019-05-09
Basketball 90  1 2019-05-09
```

where 1 is the checkbox has been checked.

I have the code below that gets the values.

```
foreach ( $_POST['activities'] as $key=>$value ) {
    $dist_activity_id = $_POST['activities'][$key];
    $dist_activity_duration = $_POST['duration'][$key];
    $dist_date = $_POST['datepicker'][$key];
    $dist_list_id = $list_id;

    if(isset($_POST['is_distance'][$key])) {
        $is_distance = $_POST['is_distance'][$key];
    } else {
        $is_distance = 0;
    }
}
```

The output doesn't keep the checkbox values in the positions there where selected, all the selected moved to the top.

```
Football   90  1 2019-05-09
Cycling    120 1 2019-05-09
Cricket    70  0 2019-05-09
Basketball 90  0 2019-05-09
```

Could someone please help with this?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (count(array_filter($_POST['duration'])) == count($_POST['duration']) && count(array_filter($_POST['datepicker'])) == count($_POST['datepicker'])) {
    foreach ( $_POST['activities'] as $key=>$value ) {
        $dist_activity_id = $_POST['activities'][$key];
        $dist_activity_duration = $_POST['duration'][$key];
        $dist_date = $_POST['datepicker'][$key];

        if(isset($_POST['is_distance'][$key])) {
            $is_distance = $_POST['is_distance'][$key];
        } else {
            $is_distance = 0;
        }                           

        $dist_list_id = $list_id;
    }

}else {
    $alert = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Please enter required fields</div>";
}
}
```

Comment: That is because If a Checkbox is NOT Checked it does not get sent to the PHP script. So you have to check if the checkbox exists in `$_POST` using an `isset()`

Comment: I've edited to include the full code. Not sure where to check `isset()`